# Undefined Symbol _memset although _memset nowhere used?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, solaris, linker-errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ["Undefined Symbol _memset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009401/undefined-symbol-memset)

I asked a similar question nowdays, but I have some update which is really confusing me. Essentially, I want to link a number of object files with the linker as follows:

```
/usr/ccs/bin/ld -o q -e [list of many object files]
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined                       first referenced 
 symbol                             in file
_memset                             reconf.o
```

The interesting things is, that memset is not referenced in reconf.c and I also grep'ed
the whole directory but there is also no reference in any of the other files to _memset. Therefore I am wondering why I get this error message from the linker, although nowhere in
my source code _memset is actually used. Anyone an idea what could be going on here?

Thanks so much, this error is driving us mental!

Comment: @Mike You can edit your original question if you need to add more info. Don't start a new identical question.

Comment: Try running the linker in verbose mode to see where the reference is to _memset. It's not at all necessary that any code you have written explicitly calls memset, but some in-built library functions might be making that call.

Comment: thanks NullPointer, I tried it with the verbose mode but the output is exactly the same... No help on why this error is occuring ...